# How to export a Kotlin Multi-Platform project to a js project?

Tags: javascript, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to create a kotlin multi-platform project which will be used be independent android, ios, and javascript projects.  The independent projects are meant to call into this library.  I've been able to export the android and ios versions but I can't figure out how to export the javascript version.

My build file looks like this:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.6.0"
    id("com.chromaticnoise.multiplatform-swiftpackage") version "2.0.3"

//    id("net.akehurst.kotlin.kt2ts") version("1.6.0")
}

group = "me.mikschn"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

kotlin.targets.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget::class.java) {
    binaries.all {
        binaryOptions["memoryModel"] = "experimental"
    }
}

kotlin {
    jvm {
        withJava()
    }
    js(LEGACY) {
        browser {
            webpackTask {
                output.libraryTarget = "commonjs2"
            }
            commonWebpackConfig {
                cssSupport.enabled = true
            }
        }
        binaries.executable()
    }
    val hostOs = System.getProperty("os.name")
    val isMingwX64 = hostOs.startsWith("Windows")

    iosArm32("nativeArm32") {
        binaries {
            framework {
                baseName = "KMPExample"
            }
        }
    }
    iosArm64("nativeArm64") {
        binaries {
            framework {
                baseName = "KMPExample"
            }
        }
    }
    iosX64("nativeX64") {
        binaries {
            framework {
                baseName = "KMPExample"
            }
        }
    }

    multiplatformSwiftPackage {
        packageName("KMPExample")
        swiftToolsVersion("5.3")
        targetPlatforms {
            iOS { v("13") }
        }
        outputDirectory(File(rootDir, "/"))
    }
    sourceSets {
        commonMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.6.0")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.0-native-mt")
                implementation("com.benasher44:uuid:0.3.1")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-datetime:0.3.1")
            }
        }

        val jvmTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:1.6.0")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.6.0-native-mt")
                implementation("org.mockito:mockito-core:4.1.0")
                implementation ("io.kotlintest:kotlintest-runner-junit5:3.3.2")
                implementation ("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.6.0")
                runtimeOnly    ("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.5.2")
                implementation ("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.5.2")
                implementation ("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.5.2")
            }
        }
        val jsMain by getting
    }
}
```

I exported the javascript build using Verdaccio.  From the folder `kmpexample/build/js/packages/KMPExample` I ran `npm publish --registry http://localhost:4873`.

The generated package.json in that folder looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "KMPExample",
  "version": "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT",
  "main": "kotlin/KMPExample.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "5.57.1",
    "webpack-cli": "4.9.0",
    "format-util": "1.0.5",
    "source-map-loader": "3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "6.3.0",
    "style-loader": "3.3.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "peerDependencies": {},
  "optionalDependencies": {},
  "bundledDependencies": []
}
```

(Note there are no references to `kotlin` or `uuid-js` which are dependencies of my kotlin project).

Then in the folder `kmpexample/jsTestApp/ts-react` (javascript app) I modified `package.json` to include `"KMPExample": "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"`.  Then I ran `yarn start` to build and run the js project.

I get these compilation errors:

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./node_modules/KMPExample/kotlin/KMPExample.js

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'kotlin' in '/Users/mikschn/workspace/kmpexample/jsTestApp/ts-react/node_modules/KMPExample/kotlin'


ERROR in ./node_modules/KMPExample/kotlin/KMPExample.js

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'uuid-js-legacy' in '/Users/mikschn/workspace/kmpexample/jsTestApp/ts-react/node_modules/KMPExample/kotlin'


ERROR in src/App.tsx:4:22

TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'KMPExample'. '/Users/mikschn/workspace/example/jsTestApp/ts-react/node_modules/KMPExample/kotlin/KMPExample.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/KMPExample` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'KMPExample';`
    2 | import logo from "./logo.svg";
    3 | import "./App.css";
  > 4 | import * as kmp from "KMPExample";
      |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    5 |
    6 | function App() {
    7 |   kmp.main()
```

It seems that the system cannot find the dependencies of my project, which are `kotlin` and `uuid-js-legacy`.

What is the right way to export my KMP project to a javascript project, so it can be called by that js project?

Comment: Can you please check with IR backend (`js(IR)`)?

Comment: I've noticed that if I add the dependencies manually (`npm install kotlin --save`) then the dependency errors go away but I still have the import error.  

Is there a way to include the dependencies automatically?  It's not ideal for users of a library to have to add the dependencies of that library, normally they added automatically which is the whole point of a package manager.

Comment: Did you check with IR backend?

Comment: I get the same result with IR backend.   For this error: `Could not find a declaration file for module 'KMPExample'.` it seems like it's a typescript problem.  Is there a way to generate typescript type data?  Or is kmp not compatible with typescript?

Comment: Can you attach a link to your project, please?